# Setup Spring Boot application to connect to different data source depending on environment parameter for the session

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, sqlite, spring-boot

I am currently building an Spring Boot application which has a requirement to work with three different database environments and behave in an environment agnostic manner.

- The "dev" environment will use a local sqlite database.
- The "uat" environment will use a postgres database.
- The "live" environment will use a sql database.

On load, my application checks for the existence of an environment parameter:

- If none is set or the environment parameter is dev, then it will create a local sqlite database and establish a connection to it for the duration of the session.
- If it is set to uat, then a connection will be established to a heroku postgres database.
- If it is set to live, then a connection will be established to a mysql database.

Now I am currently struggling to conceptualise this on Java.

This is the code I have written so far, where I get the environment parameter. Beyond this I am not sure to do.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Launcher implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(Launcher.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        String currentEnvironment = System.getenv("CURRENT_ENV");

        // if current env is null or dev, set up sqlite database (if it doesnt already exist and use this for the remainder of the session

        // if uat connect to heroku postgres db

        // if live then connect to mysql db
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the purpose of creating profiles in spring, Spring Boot allows you to have profiles that will help your application run in different environments.

So in your case you have to create three properties files for example

1. `dev.properties`
2. `uat.properties`
3. `live.properties`

In each properties files you have to set the necessary configuration for development. then just activate the profile you want to work.

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

For each one I would create a @Configuration class.

```
@Profile("dev")
@Configuration
public class DevConfiguration{
   ...
}

@Profile("uat")
@Configuration
public class UatConfiguration{
   ...
}

@Profile("live")
@Configuration
public class LiveConfiguration{
   ...
}
```

---

I would like to mention a nice book [Pro Spring Boot](https://www.apress.com/la/book/9781484214329) by Felipe Gutierrez, it can teach you a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you give me an example of how I would establish a sqlite connection or sql connection in your code for the duration of the session. For example: https://pastebin.com/qGEA82WJ. I understand spring profiles but I am not clear how to create different database connections within the context.

Comment: @methuselah are you using JPA? or a native jdbc? why you want that hard work and create your connection and statements...

Comment: @methuselah this is really hard to manage your open, close connection statements, resultsets transaction if you have, I think it is really bad idea to not move to JPA, are you familiar with [JdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) but you still put your configuration in each properties files, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

I think the real question is : how do you specify your environment ?

With Spring boot you can use several application properties files. In Your case you can use 3 files :

- application.properties (for  the dev environnement)
- application-uat.properties (for uat env)
- application-live.properties (for live env).

you can also use YAML file to do this.

There is many way to  let SpringBoot choose the right environment property file.

you have many way to choose the right environment file.

For exemple if are using tomcat  for each environnement you can set  the property spring.profiles.active 
For example `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=ENV_NAME"` (in setclasspath.bat ( setclasspath.sh if you are on  [l]unix) where ENV_NAME can be uat or live.

Comment: I specify my environment through an environment variable. See code snipped in the question. Thanks